# iPhone App Store: can I install free apps using Face ID instead of my Apple ID password?

Tags: ios-appstore

The App Store prompts me for my password for every free app I am trying to install. I have already Face ID setup for the App Store, can I use it instead? Or even the phone's passcode?

On my Macbook I have disabled the password prompt for free apps, but I'm not sure whether that's device specific.

I have tried restarting the phone and disabling Face ID for the App Store.

iOS 14.1

Comment: On your iPhone, go to Settings app → Face ID & Passcode and check if the "Use Face ID For" switch is turned on for iTunes & App Store.

Comment: @NimeshNeema It was already turned on, that is the setting I tried disabling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by enabling Face ID back:

- Settings app, Face ID & Passcode, disable for iTunes & App Store
- reboot the device (not sure that’s needed)
- Settings, Face ID, enable for the App Store